# Netbeans IDE Open Project(Browse) menu option is not working

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to install Netbeans 7.2 in my laptop. After installation "Open Project" menu option is not working, so I am unable to open existing project.

I mean "Open Project" option in the menu is not working. And "Browsing for Jar" also not working. 
Ateast It is not browsing for any project. Just simply "Open Project " menu option not working. So I am unable to open the existing Netbeans projects from my system. the only thing I can do with my Netbeans is I have to create new project from scratch.

The menu options which need to browse from computer like open Project are not working. I uninstalled& reinstalled different versions of Netbeans so many times. And formatted C drive and  reinstalled OS also, still not working.

Could any one please help me...

Comment: what java version have you installed on your laptop ?

Comment: After failed attempt open in menu **View/IDE Log** and look there for exceptions, if there are some send them here or to NB developers https://netbeans.org/community/issues.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it,

Solved problem with help of netbeans.org after reporting bug in netbeans.org

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=230339

The problem is because of "JDK Version". I had installed beta version of JDK 1.6.

Uninstalled JDK from my system, downloaded correct version from oracle website and installed.

Finally it is working after so many days of struggle.

"But I dont understand why Netbeans cant detect this at the time of installation and warn us."

Thank you guys your help and Netbeans.org for support.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the older version of Java SE Development this issue is because you have more than 1 version installed. It has nothing to do with NetBeans it is the Java SE Development.

Go to control panel / Programs / uninstall a program and find the version of Java SE and remove it.

or watch this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfmNXcOvaqI&feature=youtu.be